# Java Scanner, Delimiters, and End of Line

Tags: java

I have a data file with slash-delimited ints on multiple successive lines.
Here's a little piece of code that I'd like to use to read and print all those ints:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

class Testing {
   public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
      Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
      file.useDelimiter("/");
      while (file.hasNextInt())
         System.out.println(file.nextInt());
   }
}
```

Data file one looks like this:

```
1/2/3
4/5/6
```

Output from data file one looks like this:

```
1
2
```

Data file two looks like this:

```
1/2/3
```

Output from data file two looks like this:

```
1
2
3
```

Can someone explain why I'm getting this behavior?  In particular, why does the first example ignore the presence of the "3" at the end of the first line of data?

Note: I know several "better" ways to get my desired behavior: read the whole line at once and use split() and parseInt(), read the whole line at once and turn it into a separate Scanner object, etc.. That's not my question.  I'm trying to understand why this particular piece of code doesn't work as intended --- in particular, why I get *less* data when the file has *more* lines.

Comment: The next item in your 1st file is "3\n4" which isn't an int (so I assume hasNextInt returns false)

Comment: The delimiter is for splitting up the inputs. By using `/` you are no longer splitting up the whitespace, so the first file actually has an output of `1`, `2`, `3\n4` etc. I would read the entirety of the lines via #nextLine and follow up the result of that with a String#split call to get all your integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last `hasNextInt()` will read the element with the carriage return character.  i.e the element will be `3\r\n`.  Which is obviously not int, hence it will fail the test `file.hasNextInt()`

Answer (score 0):

When it reaches end of line 1 i.e after value 3, there is 'return character' which is not an integer. Your test of hasNextInt() starts failing from there onwards. So it only prints upto 3. i.e 1 2 3

Answer (score 0):

The has next to the end of the line one `hasNextInt()` will return a false as it return **3\r\n** so that causes the issue.

Simple solution can be -

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
      Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
      file.useDelimiter("/");
      while (file.hasNext())
         System.out.println(file.next());
   }
```

Output will now look like - 

1
2
3
4
5
6